# Android studio top level build.gradle file - how to set property of lower level build file

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

my top level build.gradle file in android studio looks like this:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }

        setProperty("buildFile",'build-ca.gradle')//system complains its read-only

    }
```

nothing special here except that im trying to set a new name for the app's build.gradle.  When i call setProperty though it complains that buildFile is a read-only property. How can i change the name of the build.gradle file ?

so to be clear im trying to use a second build.gradle file located under the app folder. My end goal is to have two build files and when i call setProperty i can switch between them.

update: thanks to the accepted answer here is what i came up with:

in gradle.properties i added this line:

```
useOtherFile=true
```

then in the settings.gradle file it look's like this:

```
boolean isOtherFile = properties['useOtherFile'] == 'true'
if(!isOtherFile)
    project(':app').buildFileName = 'build-other.gradle
```

the only bad thing is i found i have to sometimes go to file-->invalidate caches/restart in android studio for the IDE to update the build variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the same.
As I know you can't define the gradle file with a `setProperty` method.

You can define a custom name in the `settings.gradle` file.
Something like:

```
include ':app'
project(':app').buildFileName = 'mybuild.gradle'
```